# Como garantir único acesso a cada utilizador?

Tags: php

Como posso eu garantir que quanto um utilizador estiver ligado não permitir mais ligações com o mesmo *login* e *password*, tendo em conta que se a sessão expirar já pode permitir novamente ligações desse  *login* e *password*?

Estive a ler [Saber se utilizador está conectado PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39623/saber-se-utilizador-est%C3%A1-conectado-php) e fiquei com essa dúvida.

***NOTA: Sem uso de cookies***

Comment: Quero ver guardar a sessão sem cookie (até dá, mas tem que ficar passando o ID por URL). Eu acho muito mais fácil deixar logar sempre, mas a cada vez que logar, matar a sessão anterior. Muito mais simples, sem perigo de se trancar pra fora, e sem o risco de uso simultâneo. Agora, a forte impressão que eu tenho é que isso pode ter até alguma aplicação legítima, mas provavelmente serve pra tampar alguma outra falha da aplicação.

Comment: Sem cookie acho que só assim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3643602

Comment: @Bacco gostei da ideia não queres formular uma resposta?

Comment: @JorgeB. Pra falar a verdade se eu fosse responder ia preferir por naquela outra, primeiro pela restrição de cookies, que eu acho que não tem muito a ver com o problema, e apesar de pequenas diferenças na formulação, eu acho que no fim é a mesma questão. Na verdade eu nem teria muito o que acrescentar além do comment que eu fiz, seria basicamente aquilo. Logou, invalida o login anterior, apenas. Por exemplo, associando o ID da sessão ao ID do user. Se não bate, está deslogado. E ao logar, é feita nova associação, o que mataria a anterior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Através de um *handler* de sessões customizado você consegue fazer isso pois consegue executar uma rotina diferente em cada estágio da sessão: abertura, encerramento, leitura, gravação, remoção e *garbaging*.

Para criar um manipulador de sessão customizado usa-se a função [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

O handler abaixo, baseado na MySQLi, usará uma estrutura SQL simples:

```
CREATE TABLE `session_data` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `data` text,
  `last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

O *handler*:

```
class SessionSaveHandler {

    protected $link;
    protected $table;

    protected $sessionName = 'session';
    protected $maxLifeTime = 3600;

    public function __construct( $user = null, $pass = null, $host = null, $db = null, $table = null, $sessionName = null ) {

        $this -> link = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db );

        if( ! $this -> link ) {
            throw new Exception( 'Could not connect to the database!' );
        }

        mysqli_select_db( $this -> link, $db );

        session_set_save_handler(

            array( $this, 'open' ),
            array( $this, 'close' ),
            array( $this, 'read' ),
            array( $this, 'write' ),
            array( $this, 'destroy' ),
            array( $this, 'gc' )
        );

        $this -> table = $table;

        session_name( $this -> sessionName );

        session_start();
    }

    public function open( $savePath, $sessionName ) {

        $this -> sessionName = $sessionName;

        return TRUE;
    }

    public function close() {
        return true;
    }

    public function read( $id ) {

        $query = sprintf(

            'SELECT `data` FROM %s WHERE `id` = ? AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `last_updated` ) + %d > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() )',

            $this -> table, $this -> maxLifeTime
        );

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $this -> link, $query );

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 's', $id );

        if( mysqli_execute( $stmt ) ) {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result( $stmt, $retval );

            mysqli_stmt_fetch( $stmt );

            if( ! empty( $retval ) ) return $retval;
        }

        return '';
    }

    public function write( $id, $data ) {

        $query = sprintf(

            'INSERT INTO %s (id, data) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data = ?, last_updated=NULL',

            $this -> table
        );

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $this -> link, $query );

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 'sss', $id, $data, $data );

        return mysqli_execute( $stmt );
    }

    public function destroy( $id ) {

        $query = sprintf( 'DELETE FROM %s WHERE id = ?', $this -> table );

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $this -> link, $query );

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 's', $id );

        return mysqli_execute( $stmt );
    }

    public function gc( $maxlifetime ) {

        $query = sprintf(
            'DELETE FROM %s WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP( last_updated ) + %d <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() )',
            $this -> table, $this -> maxLifeTime
        );

        mysqli_query( $this -> link, $query );

        return;
    }
}
```

E seu uso:

```
require_once 'handler.php';

new SessionSaveHandler( 'root', '7v4h6q7t', 'localhost', 'session', 'session_data' );

$_SESSION['name'] = 'Bruno Augusto'; // write
$_SESSION['age']  = 26; // write

var_dump( $_SESSION['name'] ); // read

unset( $_SESSION['age'] );

var_dump( $_SESSION ); // proof
```

Esse *handler* genérico permite que os dados de sessão sejam gravados, lidos e manipulados num banco de dados. Ponto!

Agora, o que tange **realmente** o escopo do tópico é justamente customizar o comportamento. Basta, por exemplo, adicionar uma nova coluna à tabela para fazer a condição conforme o link de referência que suscitou a dúvida e modificar as queries dos métodos *SessionHandler::write()* e *SessionHandler::read()* (por segurança) para levá-la em consideração.

Dessa forma ao criar a variável de sessão, disparando assim o método *SessionHandler::write()* o índice só será criado caso a condição de existência se satisfaça.

E graças a ela, quando verificando se o índice da sessão existe para liberar acesso à determinada página, por sequer ter sido criado, tudo se resolve praticamente sozinho.

Comment: Eu fiz isso e está-me a dar NULL no `var_dump( $_SESSION );`

Comment: Assumindo que você tenha criado o banco de dados, definido o usuário e senhas diferentes dos aleatoriamente gerados que eu usei e configurado corretamente, você vai ter de ser um pouco mais específico porque quando eu escrevi eu testei e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Resolvi, esqueci-me de por `PRIMARY KEY (`id`)`. Depois apago os comentários.

Comment: Não faça isso. Se de repente alguém mais vier a ter o mesmo problema que você, já terá uma resposta.

Comment: Há qualquer coisa que não está a funcionar bem, a cada menu que vou `header('Location: index.php?menu=1');` é feito o logout na página, mas fica o registo no BD.

Comment: E cada logout que faço não apaga o registo do banco.

Comment: Eu sugeriria a você criar um novo tópico com o que você fez, a mais ou a menos, para que possamos analisar por outro ângulo. Porém, nesse meio tempo, experimente invocar session_write_close() **antes** do header(), forçando o mecanismo de sessões a gravar os dados.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42609/o-meu-sessionhandler-n%C3%A3o-me-permite-iniciar-a-sess%C3%A3o

Comment: o problema é que não apaga mesmo o registo na hora, deve ser só de x em x tempo (acho).