# O meu SessionHandler não me permite iniciar a sessão

Tags: php

Estou a utilizar [este sessionHandler](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39683/7210) como meu `sessionHandler`.

O problema é que desde que o estou a utilizar não consigo inicializar/termiar a sessão.

**index.php**

```
include_once( 'sessionHandler.php' );

$sessionHandler = new SessionSaveHandler(USER_NAME, PASSWORD, HOST, DATA_BASE,
"session", "my_session_name");

if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
    include_once 'login.php';
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    include_once 'verifica.php';
}
?>
```

```html
<form id="login-form" class="form-signin" method="post" action="">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password"/>
</form>
```

**verifica.php**

```
//se a password e o login fizerem match:

$_SESSION['id'] = $id; //retornado da query sql.
...
header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Seria possível você isolar o problema exatamente como no outro tópico? Digo, criar o BD com aquela estrutura e implementar o handler com as funções nativas da MySQLi ao invés de uma classe terceirizada?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto a minha classe `SessionSaveHandler` está exatamente igual a tua na segunda tentativa.

Comment: Não, não está. Eu não usei uma classe terceirizada para operar a MySQLi, meu construtor tinha muito mais argumentos, você removeu a propriedade *SessionSaveHandler::$table* que é usada em 4 dos 6 estágios da sessão. Isso sem contar o que pode ter sido mexido naquilo que você não mostrou.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto tem razão. Vou testar com seu exemplo sem mudar nada.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto continua a acontecer o mesmo. Ao carregar a primeira vez o index.php cria uma sessão vazia e depois não altera ao fazer login e não acessa.

Comment: Sugiro que edite a questão e mostre tudo o que está fazendo. Onde, quando e como está inicializando o SessionHandler para gravar, para para ler e remover, porque eu testei aqui novamente, com e sem redirecionamentos, com e sem nomes de sessão, e tudo funcionou perfeitamente, gravação, leitura e exclusão.

Comment: Editei a pergunta @BrunoAugusto

Comment: E os logs de erro?

Comment: Não dá nada. Apenas não preenche o campo `data` da tabela

Comment: Desculpa, mas eu insisto que deve ser alguma outra coisa que você não mostrou aqui. Eu reproduzi inclusive o seu exemplo, com essa estrutura de includes e obtive um retorno positivo através de um var_dump() adicionalmente colocado no **index.php** para depuração.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19332/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-bruno-augusto).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto vê a minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu resolvi colocando uma condição `if($data=='') return false;` no SessionHandler do Bruno para o caso dos dados virem vazios:

```
public function write( $id, $data ) {

    $query = sprintf(

        'INSERT INTO %s (id, data) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data = ?, last_updated=NULL',

        $this -> table
    );

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $this -> link, $query );

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 'sss', $id, $data, $data );

    if($data=='') return false;    

    return mysqli_execute( $stmt );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Em vez de reinventar a roda, por que não utilizar um *handler* pronto?

Um exemplo seria utilizar o [`PdoSessionHandler`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php) do *Symfony*, um *handler* que trabalha com diversos bancos de dados que pode ser encontrando dentro do [`HttpFoundation`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation).

Para utilizá-lo basta adicionar o [`symfony/http-foundation`](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-foundation) como uma dependência do seu projeto ([Como utilizar o composer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40051/como-usar-namespace-numa-classe/40511#40511)).

```
composer require symfony/http-foundation
```

Crie um arquivo para alterar o seu Session Handler a partir da função [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-set-save-handler.php):

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler;

function my_session_start()
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=test', 'root', 'root', 
                    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    $session = new PdoSessionHandler($pdo);

    // Cria as tabelas no banco: rodar só na primeira vez
    //$session->createTable();

    // Quando utilizamos uma classe como SessionHandler, 
    //os parâmetros são um pouco diferentes
    session_set_save_handler($session, true);

    // Inicia a sessão 
    session_start();
}
```

Para começar a utilizar sua sessão via banco de dados basta chama a função ou a classe que você definiu anteriormente:

```
<?php

require_once 'session_tuned.php';

my_session_start();

$_SESSION['id'] = '213';
$_SESSION['nome'] = 'garoto';

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Exemplo no [GitHub](https://github.com/gmsantos/customSessionHandler).